# Validation bypass

Tags: validation-rule

The validation rule gets bypassed if it's Outgoing and Incoming Call not selected. Any free text can be used to save without the validation rule firing. How to amend to prohibit users from creating or saving the task (any freetext) without populating WhoID or User? The OR section is used for SMS Magic.

```
AND(ISBLANK(WhoId),
ISBLANK(User__c), OR
(Subject = 'Outgoing Call',
Subject = 'Incoming Call'),
Subject != 'SMS Sent',
Subject != 'SMS Received')
```

Comment: Do you want to make WhoId or User Mandatory?

Comment: Yes precisely, the user should to nominate either user or name (whoid) mandatory.

Comment: Your current validation fires when both are blank. Meaning if `whoId` or `user` is filled, you wont get error. This meets your requirement. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Using `OR` with not equals will *always* return true.

Comment: The validation works Yes, but if the User to populate the subject with ABCD apart then selective picklist (Incoming or Outgoing), he will be able to save the Task without User or Name. AND(ISBLANK(WhoId),
ISBLANK(User__c), OR

(Subject = Null,
Subject = 'Outgoing Call',
Subject = 'Incoming Call'),
Subject != 'SMS Sent',
Subject != 'SMS Received') Used the above formula but User and Name can be avoided from set mandatory

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want anything that is not an SMS subject having a blank who or user. In your original rule both whoId and user__c must be blank for it to evaluate to true in addition to the subject being equal to Outgoing call or incoming call. Thus leaving free text allowed and either who or user to be blank as well.

The below will evaluate to true when either who or user is blank for any subject other than the SMS

```
AND(
    OR(
       ISBLANK(WhoId),
       ISBLANK(User__c)
    ), 
    Subject != 'SMS Sent',
    Subject != 'SMS Received'
)
```

If you only want it to fire if the subject has a value then this would be the adjustment

```
AND(
    OR(
       ISBLANK(WhoId),
       ISBLANK(User__c)
    ),
    NOT(ISBLANK(Subject)), 
    Subject != 'SMS Sent',
    Subject != 'SMS Received'
)
```